# How to use signicant figures?

Tags: significant-figures

I am confused about significant figures. In a teaching video, the teacher showed this math:

$$ 22.2 + 22.2 + 30.10 + 30.10 = 104.6$$

This is, of course, the actual answer, but in using significant figure count the answer would be $105$, because:

```
22.2---- 3 significant numbers

22.2---- 3 significant numbers

30.10--- 4 significant numbers

30.10--- 4 significant numbers

+______

104.6
```

The first number has the fewest significant figures, so we would "round" to 3 significant numbers in our answer. I emailed the course helpline, but they sent a confusing email back about differences in counting the significant numbers whether you are adding and subtracting, or multiplying and dividing. I need help explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule you are applying is for multiplication and division.  For addition and subtraction look at the numbers in the problem.  22.2 is accurate to the tenths place so the answer can be reported to the tenths place regardless of how many sig figs are in the answer.

Comment: good answer, but could I maybe see some math to see the difference?

Comment: 22.2+30.10 = 52.3.  The number 22.2 is accurate to the tenths place.  We do not know what the digit in the hundredths place is.  It could be 0-5.  So, the answer can only be expressed to the tenths place.  The multiplication and division makes less sense.  35X3 = 105.  The lowest number of sig figs in the problem is one, so the answer can only have one sig fig.  We express the answer as 100.